# The lie algebra of the orthogonal group of an arbitrary space time metric

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, linear-algebra

Let X ad Y be two vectors in R<sup>4</sup>, and define the inner product of X and Y as:

(X*Y) = g<sub>ik</sub>X<sub>i</sub>Y<sub>k</sub>  (summation convention for repeated indicies)

Then we consider the 4x4 matrix g whose components are g<sub>ik</sub>.  I am of course interested in the case that g is NOT positive definite, because this is the situation when g represents the gravitational field in general relativity.

Let A be a 4x4 matrix which satisfies (X*Y) = (AX*AY), then I say that A is an element O(g), the orthogonal group determined by g.

I am interested in finding any sort of formula which relates the lie algebra of O(g) to the metric g.

In a previous question, it was suggested that I diagonalize the matrix g using the theorem on diagonalizing positive definite matrices.  This method works nicely and gives a simple solution for the lie algebra in terms of the transformation matrix which diagonalizes g, but only when g is positive definite.

Can I still diagonalize my non positive definite g by finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial?  I believe I must first somehow restrict the set of vectors I allow the inner product to work on, to avoid the case (X*Y) = 0.  Nevertheless, for arguments sake let's assume that I can diagonalize g.

Let B be the transformation matrix, then I assume that I can write:

g = B<sup>-1</sup>ηB, where η is the identity matrix of signature (1,3), i.e. the metric of flat space time.

We can characterize the elements of O(g) by realizing that our inner product can be written as:

(X*Y) = X<sup>T</sup>gY

It's clear that if A is an element of O(g), then

(AX*AY) = X<sup>T</sup>A<sup>T</sup>gAY = X<sup>T</sup>gY

Hence, A<sup>T</sup>gA = g

This formula can be written as gA<sup>-1</sup>g = A<sup>T</sup>, since g = g<sup>-1</sup> explicitly.

Now applying the transformation matrix B:

gA<sup>-1</sup>g = B<sup>-1</sup>ηBA<sup>-1</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>ηB = A<sup>T</sup>, which I rearrange as:

ηBA<sup>-1</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>η = BA<sup>T</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>

If by some chance (BA<sup>-1</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>)<sup>-1</sup> = (BA<sup>T</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>)<sup>T</sup>, then I can immediately conclude that A is in O(g) so long as BA<sup>-1</sup>B<sup>-1</sup> is in O(1,3) (the group which preserves the metric η).  From this step is it quite straightforward to compute the lie algebra, by taking advantage of the formula Be<sup>X</sup>B<sup>-1</sup> = e<sup>BXB<sup>-1</sup></sup>.

I am concerned about several steps of this procedure:

1) Is it legal to diagonalize g?  I believe I need exclude any combination of vectors X, Y for which (X*Y) = 0.  Since the squared norm is (X*X), then this amounts to disregarding vectors which lie along geodesic paths.  Then I can deal separately for the case (X*X) > 0 and (X*X) < 0.

2) How am I supposed to deal with the condition that (BA<sup>-1</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>)<sup>-1</sup> = (BA<sup>T</sup>B<sup>-1</sup>)<sup>T</sup>?  This condition seems quite restrictive.

Comment: If you are talking about relativity, then you mean that $g$ is a quadratic form of signature $(3,1)$. Then up to a change of coordinates, you can assume it is the usual Lonretz form. Its group is called $O(3,1)$ and any textbook on bilinear algebra shall contain everything you want.

This is fairly classical and does not fit MO as far as I understand it.

Comment: Another point: a change of coordinates P acts on g  by $P^t g P$, not by $P^{-1} g P$ since we are talking of bilinear forms, not of endomorphisms.

Comment: I am well aware of the lie algebra of the lorentz group, naturally.  Is this the reference you are referring me to?  I believe my group O(g) is quite distinct from O(3,1), since O(3,1) is a special case of O(g) when g is the flat space time metric.

For example, the spin group and lorentz group have different lie algebras, and both are derived by substiting a specific g into the formulas in my post.

Comment: To repeat in more detail what Benoît has already tried to explain: Given any non-degenerate symmetric matrix $g$, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^tgP$ is diagonal and contains only $1$ or $-1$ along the diagonal. If there are $p$ $1$'s and $q$ $-1$'s, then we say that it has signature $(p,q)$. In other words, using a change of co-ordinates you can always assume that $g$ is diagonal with only ones or negative-ones along the diagonal. In particular, if $g$ is signature $(3,1)$, then the Lie group and algebra of $g$ is isomorphic to $O(3,1)$ and $o(3,1)$.

Comment: I don't believe the invere of the transformation matrix P is it's own transpose in general, because this would only be true for positive def matrices, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: No one is claiming that in general $P^{-1} = P^t$. What Benoît is trying to explain is that if you change co-ordinates using a linear transformation $P$, then the metric in the new co-ordinates is given by $P^tgP$ and *not* $P^{-1}gP$.

Comment: The condition that the inverse is the transpose is precisely the condition that P is orthogonal, not that it is positive-definite. 

Comment: @Matt: you make a comment about the possibility of $g$ being flat. Just to make sure we are all talking about the same thing: are the entries of your matrix g functions on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @michael, yes for sure since that is the case in general relativity.

Comment: @Matt: ok, maybe I have to continue asking: the entries of A and the entries of the X are also functions?

Comment: The question as written makes sense only if $g$ is a fixed matrix that defines a nondegenerate quadratic form on $R^4$, i.e. an indefinite flat metric. If $g$ is a nonconstant (and not necessarily flat) function of $R^4$, then what the heck is $O(g)$?

Comment: @Michael, the entries of the vectors X are real numbers, and the entries of A should be functions of 4 real parameters.  This can be seen by analogy with rotations in three space, for which the lie algebra corresponds to the three principle axis, and the three real parameters which elements of O(3) depend on correspond to rotations about the principle axis.  

Comment: @Deane, I am confused by your most recent comment.  

1) Are you implying that if g is a non degenerate matrix, that it must be the matrix corresponding to the metric of flat space time?

2) g is just a matrix, and the entries of g are functions g(i,k) from R4 -> R.  I don't think of g as a function on R4, its just a matrix that can be used to represent the inner product as defined in the OP.  Has your issue been cleared up by david speyers excellent answer given below?  If not, can you please elaborate your objection because I am interested in the problem you see here.

Comment: Matt, Speyer's answer makes sense if the entries of $g$ are real numbers and not real-valued functions on $R^4$. In that case, the Lie group $O(g)$ and Lie algebra $o(g)$ both make sense, and Speyer explains very nicely what they are. What others have tried to explain is that $O(g)$ is isomorphic to the Lie group and $o(g)$ is isomorphic to the Lie algebra associated with the diagonal matrix of $1$'s and $-1$'s with the same number of positive and negative eigenvalues as $g$. But none of this makes sense if the entries of $g$ are functions. 

Comment: If $g$ is a real symmetric matrix whose signature is $(+,+,+,-)$, then it defines a flat space-time metric. If $g$ is a real non-degenerate symmetric matrix (but not necessarily of the right signature), then it defines a flat semiriemannian metric on $R^4$ equivalent to the standard one defined using a diagonal matrix with the right number of $+1$'s and $-1$'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to diagonalize. You are looking at the group of those $A$ such that $A g A^T = g$. Putting $A=1+ \epsilon B$ for some small $\epsilon$, you want $(1+\epsilon B)g(1+\epsilon B^T) = g$ or $\epsilon(Bg+g B^T) = O(\epsilon^2)$. So the Lie algebra you want is $\{ B : Bg+gB^T=0 \}$.   Since $g=g^T$, this can also be stated as the set of $B$ such that $Bg$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: I really like this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(1) There is no difficulty in diagonalizing the quadratic form $g$, regardless of its signature.  However, you must be careful: either $g = B^{-1} \eta B$, where $B$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\eta$ is an arbitrary diagonal matrix of signature (3,1), or $g = B^T \eta B$, where $B$ may not be orthogonal, but $\eta$ is the signature-(3,1) identity matrix.

(2) I am somewhat puzzled by your assertion that $g = g^{-1}$.  This will not be true for most metrics (although it might be true for the case you care about).

(3) In any case, here's how I think the calculation ought to go.  From the formula $A^TgA=g$, we get
$$
gA^{-1} g^{-1} = A^T,
$$
which, after substituting in $g = B^T \eta B$, becomes
$$
B^T \eta B A^{-1} B^{-1} \eta B^{-T} = A^T,
$$
which can be rearranged as
$$
\eta B A^{-1} B^{-1} \eta = B^{-T} A^T B^T,
$$
or
$$
\eta (B A B^{-1})^{-1} \eta = (BAB^{-1})^T.
$$
As you can see, $A$ is an element of $O(g)$ if and only if $BAB^{-1}$ lies in $O(1,3)$

Comment: I am a little concerned about transforming g to the identity matrix with signature (3,1).  How can we be sure that the eigenvalue's of g are all 1 or -1?

Comment: If you view $g$ as a symmetric matrix, its eigenvalues are not necessarily all $1$ or $-1$. See, however, the comments below your question.